# Get Group from GroupDescription

Tags: c#, wpf, list

Say I have a bunch of Books stored in BooksList. Each Book has a genre, for example: adventure, mystery, or sci-fi.

I can group the Books by genre by adding a GroupDescription for the "genre" property.

Given BooksList and the GroupDescription "genre", how can I retrieve the list of all genres? (adventure, mystery, sci-fi).

My use-case is wanting to create a dropdown for my view that can filter by genre. I'm planning to bind the dropdown items to the list of genres.

EDIT: Also, in my use-case, the descriptor "genre" is only known at runtime. So the answer to my problem cannot rely on hardcoding "genre".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `DistinctBy` method in [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) library:

`var query = booksList.DistinctBy(p => p.GroupDescription);`

Comment: How can I add the library to call DistinctBy?

Comment: Please use [MoreLINQ](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/). I'm sorry, I should've mentioned that before.